# Shape of chamber in thermodynamic machine

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine

Why doesn't the shape of the chamber in a thermodynamic machine/heat engine influence the efficency?
Wouldn't a bell / parabola / cone shaped chamber help turn brownian motion into mechanical work of the piston?

Sorry if this question is not precise

Answer (score 2):

For a [theoretical heat engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_engine) studied in thermodynamics courses the shape doesn't matter. Indeed, the system is assumed to be a gas in thermodynamic equilibrium, and its state and effect on the environment is fully characterized by its pressure (which is the same at every point of the surface of the chamber.)

When the engine functions, the shape of the chamber changes very slowly ([*quasistatically*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasistatic_process)), so that the equilibrium assumption holds true at every moment to the required level of precision.

This is not the case in a real heat engine - like the internal combustion engine or steam engine - where the cycle happens over a finite time, and one has to account for how quickly the working substance is heated, how the heat propagates in it, how the substance flows between different parts of the engine, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have expressed your question is somewhat ambiguous.

One answer to the wording of your question is that, in the thermodynamic limit in which we are saying that these things apply, the system in question is already so large in all dimensions that the boundaries are basically not important. In particular, it is so not-important that we are actually imagining that the gas chamber is actually infinitely large, and we are simply mentally chopping out a slice of the infinitely large gas box by a part that is exactly the precise shape and size of the chamber and hoping that the difference does not matter.

But I think what you are actually interested in, is closer to Feynman talking about [the ratchet when used under thermodynamics.](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_46.html)